# Forcing shot of night sky

Tags: nikon, lighting, astrophotography

I want shots of the night sky with my Nikon D5600. Even in bulb mode and on manuel, and on a tripod, I can’t get the shutter to open. I just get that annoying “subject is too dark” message! I set focus to infinity, but still no shot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the camera say Subject is too Dark and refuse to click the shutter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/why-does-the-camera-say-subject-is-too-dark-and-refuse-to-click-the-shutter)

Comment: You may want to switch to live view and zoom in on a star to fine tune the focus. Setting a lens to infinity does not always work well. It only works if the lens has a 'hard infinity stop', and if it is set correctly.

Comment: [Related](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/88805/15871)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to the duplicate question in the comment above.

Basically, you cannot release, as the camera cannot acquire critical focus via autofocus. You have to switch the camera to manual focus as well.